# How to log WCF message content?

Tags: .net, wcf, logging

[image]

I thought this would be simple, but I can't see how to tell WCF to log message bodies. I have:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EntLibLoggingProxyTraceListener,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
          name="traceListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
     <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
   </diagnostics>
   ...etc..,
   ...etc...
</system.Model>
<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
   <listeners>
     <add fileName="_trace-xml.log"
                listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.XmlTraceListenerData,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
                traceOutputOptions="None"
                type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.XmlTraceListener,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
        name="XML Trace Listener" />      
     ...etc... other listeners
  </listeners>
  ...etc...
</loggingConfiguration>
```

But all I get logged is stuff about the message, not the message body. What do I need to change to log message content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need message bodies, you'll have to capture them yourself, programatically. Use a service behavior to install a message inspector and capture messages inside your implementation of IDispatchMessageInspector or IClientMessageInspector.

Comment: Alas. So does something like this blog http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/iclientmessageinspector/ give me *everything* I need or is there more that I need to know in terms of config or code to log message bodies?

Comment: That link is pretty much everything you need. The only thing it doesn't show is how to install the endpoint behavior, which is pretty easy (endpoint.Behaviors.Add).

Comment: This answer is wrong. Configuring a source for `System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging` and a listener to log the messages works fine for me. There is no message inspector required.

Comment: Wrong! As @TomW said, you can simply configure a source to receive the message.

Comment: For others inclined to call this answer wrong and claim it all just works in config, I refer you to @RichardHowells' answer : “I found an versioning issue. When the WCF Service project was built against .Net 3.5 I saw the full message body in the viewer tool. Built against .Net 4.0 I saw no message body.”

Answer (score 41):

Just following this description works perfectly for me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
             <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
<messageLogging 
     logEntireMessage="true" 
     logMalformedMessages="false"
     logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
     logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
     maxMessagesToLog="3000"
     maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

No need to write any code for that ...

Comment: If I do this I get tons of info about what WCF is doing, but nothing about the contents of the messages:

Comment: That is weird. Can you post a screenshot of your svcviewer.exe that has loaded the messages.svclog and shows the content of the messages tab?

Comment: <ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord ...Severity="Verbose">
 <TraceIdentifier>...</TraceIdentifier>
 <Description>A message was read</Description>
 <AppDomain>...</AppDomain>
 <Source>System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage/48266778</Source>
 <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord">
 <MessageProperties>
 <Encoder>...</Encoder>
 </MessageProperties>
 <MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders>
 </ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>

Comment: grrr. Anyway the above attempts to demonstrate that the svclog element for 'process action 'getBlah' the 'sent a message over a channel' entry does not in fact log the message in question, but just has an empty <MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders> and no MessageBody or anysuch. Other trace items such as 'a message was written' and 'Http response was received also contain no message info. Not sure how to post a screenshot.

Comment: You know svctraceviewer, right? http://www.matlus.com/svctraceviewer-debugging-wcf-sevices/. Load you svclog file there.

Comment: Screenshot posted, although you'd need several to prove that none of the tracerecords contain a message body? Having spent some time yesterday googling on this I got the impression that JohnC was right and that something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=VS.90).aspx was the solution that blogs tended to imitate. I'm on Net3.5 if it makes a difference

Comment: If you do not see ANYTHING on the MESSAGE tab in svtraceviewer (which is not clear from your screenshot, because you do not have that tab activated) you are NOT doing message logging. Are you ABSOLUTELY sure you are using the LITERAL example my answer provides? (Guess not, because the filename in the header is different).

Comment: @kroonwijk thanks for the info. Didn't realize that was possible. Does this technique log protocol messages as well, or only application messages?

Comment: @JohnC: The example in the answer is only logging WCF and SOAP related "application" messages. For protocol logging, you would need to change the source to System.Net and System.Net.Sockets as explained in http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2007/05/23/debugging-ssltls-problems-in-net/

Comment: @kroonwijk: sorry to have rudely disappeared from the thread, I've in hospital; I'll be back shortly with the next screenshot. Thx, Chris

Comment: Okay: I confirm that the Messages Tab (in the top left Activity, Project, Message, Graph tabgroup) IS empty. (As is the Message tab in the bottom right Formatted-Xml-Message tabgroup). We could hypothesis that logEntireMessage just works in VS2010/.Net 4; and just doesn't work in Vs2008/.Net 3; and this is why there is a spattering of blogs and a MS magazine article on the route indicated by JohnC's response. Or there is something crucial I've missed; but I have the same config as you've indicated in your answer and it don't work for me.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll It works for me in VS2008/.NET 3, I had to increase the maxSizeOfMessageToLog (as this limit above is 2000 bytes and some of my messages were larger)

Comment: This works. You may want to increase maxSizeOfMessageToLog

Answer (score 3):

I found an versioning issue.  When the WCF Service project was built against .Net 3.5 I saw the full message body in the viewer tool.  Built against .Net 4.0 I saw no message body.

Comment: Ahhh so irritating! This seems to be it!.. one of those "you only need it when something goes wrong".

Comment: To the people having trouble with this on .Net 4.0. Pay attention,

Tracing is:

   `<source name="System.ServiceModel">`

Messages are:

    `<source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">` 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264260/wcf-how-do-i-trace-message-bodies

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.csharptutorial.in/12/csharp-net-wcf-how-to-enable-wcf-tracing-and-messagelogging and setup logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true". In your log file you can find `<s:Body>` tags. Investigate text near them. Later you can add new "XmlListener" and found the message body in more flexible format.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider another way to see XML SOAP - [**custom MessageEncoder**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder). The main difference from similar IDispatchMessageInspector / IClientMessageInspector is that it works on lower level, so it captures original byte content including any malformed xml.

In order to implement tracing using this approach you need to wrap a standard [textMessageEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) with [custom message encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder) as new [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and apply that custom binding to endpoint in your [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding).

Also you can see as example how I did it in my project -
[wrapping](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingBindingElement.cs) textMessageEncoding, logging [encoder](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingEncoder.cs), custom binding [element](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingExtensionElement.cs) and [config](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/UsageExamples/ExampleBeta/Client/App.config).