# WCF: How do I trace message bodies?

Tags: wcf, logging, trace

I'm trying to diagnose a WCF service that is self-hosted in a relatively simple service host process (Service.exe).

I have Service.exe.config configured thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
              switchValue="All"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData= "c:\temp\Service.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="1"
                      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647"
                      logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
                      sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

When I look at the resulting svclog file, I see many trace events being logged (I expected only the first message to be logged), and none of the messages being traced show a message body (only headers).

I'm sure I must be missing something simple here, but I don't see it.

UPDATE: When I look at the WCF Config Editor, there are two sections under "Diagnostics": MessageLogging and Tracing. When I click the "EnableMessageLogging" link, my config file gets updated:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add initializeData="c:\temp\MessageBodyTracing.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            name="traceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\messagebodytracing\messagebodytracing\app_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

I guess the source named System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging is the key - I hadn't seen that in any documentation of message tracing...

Comment: Why is `maxMessagesToLog="1"`? Is it on purpose?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see if ANYTHING in the <messageLogging> section was taking effect, and it appears not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add:

```
<endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
```

in your `diagnostics` node, under `messageLogging`.

Comment: Didn't help. I've even tried this with the "Hello World" service you get when creating a new WCF Service Library project, and I don't get the message bodies logged there, either. Confused.

Comment: Have you tried to use the WCF configuration editor from VS and see what's generated for your service .config?

Answer (score 3):

Set **LogEntireMessage** to true under Diagnostics->MessageLogging in the Service configuration Editor

Comment: This just makes it so it shows "...stream..." in the viewer

Comment: @Joe Phillips TransferMode is set to Streaming. Tracing only works when setting TransferMode to Buffered! You'll have to change your configuration.